# GPS navigation in Google maps iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gpsd

I am working on Google maps,and I am new to it.Actually I want to show navigation symbol on Google maps when I move to position A to position B following the path i have drawn.I want to animate or move the map and compass button direction as I am moving my device without touching it in same direction.Please help me how would i do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compass changes, it will execute the function and you can change the direction.

You can use the function below.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading { 
if (newHeading.headingAccuracy > 0) {
CGFloat heading = (1.0f * M_PI * newHeading.trueHeading) / 180.f;
myLocationAnnotationView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(heading);}}
```

this image illustrates the situation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help, But i want to show navigation like google maps do with navigation icon .How would i use that?.Please let me know.